# Placing a responsive icon in the center of the grid

Tags: html, css

how can I put an icon in the middle of a page in a grid that has several items and it is completely responsive? I used a position that is on the rest of the items but takes into account the range of motion on the whole screen while I expect the range of motion to be entirely within the range of the same grade as the photos.

```css
.icon--art {
  width: 200px;
}

.icon--wavy-edges-circle {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 0 #f3ede9);
  opacity: 0.95;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<section class="container art__block">
  <article class="grid grid--1×2">
    <div class="art__content"> somethings... </div>
    <div class="art__gallery grid grid--2×2">
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <div>
        <svg class="icon--art icon--wavy-edges-circle">
              <use href="images/sprite.svg#wavyEdgesCircle"></use>
            </svg>
        <span class="art__img-text">TASTES SO GOOD!</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give `position: relative` to your grid container `<article class="grid grid--1×2">`.
It will make your image to bound to that container and stay in the middle of that grid.
For responsive size, give `width` to your image with units that is responsive `%` or `vw`